# Cannot clear away BitDefender Internet Security system tray message

Tags: anti-virus, notifications, bitdefender

I have BitDefender IS 2008 installed on my PC. In the last few days I have noticed the taskbar icon grumbling

> 1 issue requires your attention

The Real-Time File Scanning is disabled and no amount of clicking "Fix" solved this issue. I have tried umpteen reboots and what have you. I really don't want to uninstall and re-install BitDefender (unless there's no other way out).

How do I clear away the notification message?

Answer (score 0):

You could try restoring the settings to default, seeing if that clears the message

Then just the trouble of systematically turning features to what you want one by one and seeing if the error pops up

Answer (score -1):

Also, I hate to say it, but 3 years is a long time in the world of antivirus software. Even though the software can still receive updates, the newer versions probably fix bugs and maybe offer protection features that the 2008 version does not. You might also shop around and see if you want to continue with bitdefender or try one of the others. http://av-comparatives.org/ does performance tests of all the major antivirus programs, you can see which programs are doing well lately.